# Environment variables from env fiile in entrypoint in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, entry-point

I would like to use variable from env-file in docker-compose in entry point:

```
  # environment.env
  HOST=example.com

  # docker-compose.yml
  some_service:
    ...
    env_file: ['environment.env']
    entrypoint: ['myexecutable', '--host', '$HOST']
```

Is there any way to do that? I found only one solution:

```
  # docker-compose.yml
  some_service:
    ...
    env_file: ['environment.env']
    entrypoint: sh -c 'myexecutable --host $$HOST'
```

But it looks violates docker conception "one process per container" (because there will be 2 processes: `sh` and `myexecutable`). And container does not stop normally, I have to kill it with `docker kill` or `docker-compose kill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have just a single process you can run `sh -c 'exec myexecutable --host ...'` so that it will take over as the single process. Although the "one process per container" generally means that you don't run a process supervisor. It's not that uncommon for one process to start others.

To have the command exit properly on SIGTERM you need to setup explicit signal handlers. You can do that with `trap` in bash, or in the application itself. See also https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#why-do-my-services-take-10-seconds-to-recreate-or-stop

Comment: Entrypoint `exec myexecutable` does not work for me: it says that `Container command not found or does not exist.`; Do entrypoint `sh -c 'exec myexecutable --host $$HOST'` will be correct solution according docker philosophy?

Comment: sorry I meant `sh -c 'exec ...'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the env file, but if it's an environment variable already in your shell session, you can use it within the docker-compose file with `${your_env_var_here}`

Comment: Question is exactly about env-file, because it stores configuration for the service...